# How to move a shape everytime a button is pressed javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to get this circle to move by 120 pixels to the right each time I press a button, but it's not working.

```
double CircleX = 240;
double CircleY = 360;
            
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        Group root = new Group();

        //This is the circle I want to move whenever I press the button
        Circle circle = new Circle(CircleX,CircleY,50);
        
        //The button
        Button MoveRight = new Button("->");
        MoveRight.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent e) ->{
            CircleX += 120;
        });
        
        root.getChildren().addAll(circle, MoveRight);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1680,960,Color.SKYBLUE);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());         
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

I think I have to redraw the canvas every couple milliseconds, but I'm not sure how. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to update the x coordinate. Add `circle.setCenterX(CircleX);` in your event handler. Primitive types like int are passed-by-value.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to update Circle X position.
To do it, add this: `circle.setCenterX(CircleX);` into event handler.
It should look like:

```
MoveRight.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent e) ->{
       CircleX += 120;
       circle.setCenterX(CircleX);
});
```

Edit:
If you want update circle Y position, just add:

```
circle.setCenterY(CircleY);
```

Into your event handler.

Hope helps ;)

Comment: I didn't know I had to do that, Thanks guys!

Comment: java naming conventions please - don't replicate their violations in the question, they tend to stick :)